# Chrome packaged apps onActive

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Is there any way to handle Chrome packaged appWindow active/inactive state?
The events something like this `onActive` or `onFocus`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AppWindow does not provide this, but the standard DOM window does via window.onfocus and window.onblur.

e.g:

```
function windowLostFocus() {
  stopPlayingMusic();
}

window.onblur = windowLostFocus;
```

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't, but there is an API being added right now that will do something close to what you need. Until it's landed, we can't be 100% sure about the final shape, but you will get something along the lines of:

```
chrome.app.window.isVisible
chrome.app.window.onShown
chrome.app.window.onHidden
```

...etc.

You can follow the progress in this discussion thread at apps-dev group:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/apps-dev/EZYnJeKI6zw